# Return a list of all Active Directory application groups a user belongs to

Tags: c#, .net, windows, active-directory

I want to list all the Active Directory application groups a user belongs to. But I got nothing.

Thanks for advice.

```
public List<string> GetGroups(string strUserName)
{
        DirectoryEntry objADAM = default(DirectoryEntry);
        // Binding object.          
        DirectoryEntry objGroupEntry = default(DirectoryEntry);
        // Group Results.
        DirectorySearcher objSearchADAM = default(DirectorySearcher);
        // Search object.
        SearchResultCollection objSearchResults = default(SearchResultCollection);
        // Results collection.
        string strPath = null;
        // Binding path.
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        // Construct the binding string.
        strPath = "LDAP://CHCAD.abc/DC=abc";
        //Change to your ADserver 
        // Get the AD LDS object.
        try
        {
            objADAM = new DirectoryEntry(strPath);
            objADAM.RefreshCache();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        // Get search object, specify filter and scope,
        // perform search.  
        try
        {
            objSearchADAM = new DirectorySearcher(objADAM);
            objSearchADAM.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group)(samaccountname=" + strUserName + "))";
            objSearchADAM.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            objSearchResults = objSearchADAM.FindAll();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        // Enumerate groups 
        try
        {
            if (objSearchResults.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (SearchResult objResult in objSearchResults)
                {
                    objGroupEntry = objResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    result.Add(objGroupEntry.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("No groups found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find a user - this will search for DN and samAccountName and display name and a few more
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, strUserName);

if(user != null)
{
   // if user is found - get the groups that user belongs to
   PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> authGroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

   List<string> groupNames = new List<string>();

   foreach(Principal group in authGroups)
   {
      // do something with the groups - like add their name to a List<string>
      groupNames.Add(group.Name);  
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

**PS:** otherwise, if you cannot switch to S.DS.AM, you should check out [my answer to another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264028/directoryentry-invokegroups-null-not-retrieving-all-groups) that deals with the same issue. Basically just check out the `memberOf` property of your `DirectoryEntry` object.

Comment: Can I convert Principal group into a string list so I can check the results during debugging?

Comment: @Love: you can look at `group.Name` to get the group's name - yes.

Comment: It only returned a few groups not all groups. And got an exception "NoMatchingPrincipalException occurred".

Comment: @Love: the call is `.GetAuthorizationGroups()` - so it will not return distribution groups. You can also try `.GetGroups()` that will return **all** groups - but it won't recursively enumerate those groups.